# Query was empty PHP MySQL Table Error

Tags: php, mysql

In this php script I am accessing to a main table called 'album_name' and thus accessing another dynamic table according to the table 'album_name'. When I am tried to access it through nesting 2 while loops it got an error. Then I tried to retrieve values from the main table 'album_name' and store it into an array. Then only it is put into another loop to access the dynamic table with name recieved from the main table.  But it shows 'Query was empty'

```
<?php       
    $i=0;
    $querya = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM album_name");
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($querya)) {
        $alb['$i']=str_replace(' ', '', $data['album_id']);
        $i++;
        //echo '<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="'.str_replace(' ', '', $data['album_id']).'">';
    }
    foreach ($alb as $albu ) {
            # code...
        $queryb = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".$albu);
        $result = mysql_query($queryb) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result )) {
            echo '<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="'.$albu.'">';
            echo '<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".'.$alb['$i'].'">';   
            echo '<img src="images/gallery/'.$row['img_title'].'.jpg" class="img-rounded col-md-3 gal-img" /></a>';
            echo '<!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade '.$row['album_name'].'" id="myModal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">'.$row['img_title'].'</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <img src="images/doctors/dr.maya/'.$row['img_title'].'.jpg" class="gal-img-pop" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
        }
        $i--;
    }                  
?>
```

Comment: *"...while loops it got an error"* -- which is? I already know part of the answer. **Clue:** *It's not rhum & coke.*

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if you're not already doing so, and debug yourself. No better way to learn ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes around $i. Change this:

```
 $alb['$i']=str_replace(' ', '', $data['album_id']);
```

into this:

```
 $alb[$i]=str_replace(' ', '', $data['album_id']);
```

Here is complete code:

```
<?php       
    $i=0;
    $querya = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM album_name");
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($querya)) {
        $alb[$i]=str_replace(' ', '', $data['album_id']);
        $i++;
        //echo '<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="'.str_replace(' ', '', $data['album_id']).'">';
    }
    foreach ($alb as $albu ) {
            # code...
        $queryb = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".$albu);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryb)) {
            echo '<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="'.$albu.'">';
            echo '<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".'.$alb['$i'].'">';   
            echo '<img src="images/gallery/'.$row['img_title'].'.jpg" class="img-rounded col-md-3 gal-img" /></a>';
            echo '<!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade '.$row['album_name'].'" id="myModal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">'.$row['img_title'].'</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <img src="images/doctors/dr.maya/'.$row['img_title'].'.jpg" class="gal-img-pop" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
        }
        $i--;
    }                  
?>
```

Comment: Could be part of the problem, but do go over OP's code *very carefully*.

Comment: OP says *"not working"* and answer gets a +1. *baffled* --- I'd of gotten shot down for that one.

Comment: You are mixing mysql and mysqli functions here.
$queryb = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".$albu);
$result = mysql_query($queryb) or die(mysql_error());

Remove the line with $result, and do the while on $queryb (and not $result). The while loop should look like this:
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryb))

Comment: I have updated my answer with complete code. Please be more specific in what is not working. Is the first query returning the right result?  Is the system entering the foreach loop?

Comment: As Fred suggested, Add error reporting to the top of your file(s)  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);